# Массив целых чисел Objective-C

Tags: массивы, objective-c

Подскажите, вот мне надо в программе заполнять массив, который должен содержать целые числа    (последовательность действий пользователя). Я так понял, что Класса реализующего тип инт нет?

Все, что мне пришло в голову это держать переменную типа int *tmp; и перед тем как записывать число в массив мне надо выделить ей память, записать число, потом передать на добавление в массив NSMutableArray ?

Может есть какой-то другой способ, которого я не знаю, подскажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я так понял, что Класса реализующего тип инт нет?

Такой класс есть - это и есть NSNumber. Этот класс является контейнером для всех основных скалярных типов С. Вот отрывок из [документации NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
Creating an NSNumber Object

+ numberWithBool:
+ numberWithChar:
+ numberWithDouble:
+ numberWithFloat:
+ numberWithInt:
+ numberWithInteger:
+ numberWithLong:
+ numberWithLongLong:
+ numberWithShort:
+ numberWithUnsignedChar:
+ numberWithUnsignedInt:
+ numberWithUnsignedInteger:
+ numberWithUnsignedLong:
+ numberWithUnsignedLongLong:
+ numberWithUnsignedShort:
```

Суть в том, что в зависимости от того, какой из этих методов Вы вызываете, NSNumber при своей инициализации за кулисами выбирает соответствующий интерфейс для работы с типом, который Вы ему передаёте. Я выражаюсь тут не совсем точно, для более детального изучения ищите вещи вроде: `NSNumber class cluster` и что-нибудь вроде `NSNumber, boxing`. Для Вашей же задачи должно быть более чем достаточно следующего:

Вот Вам подробный пример для работы с числами типа int:

```
int N = 10;
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    NSNumber *intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i + 1];

    // Или
    // NSNumber *intNumber = @(i + 1);

    [numbers addObject:intNumber];
}

NSLog(@"Numbers %@", numbers);
```

И наоборот, чтобы потом превратить NSNumber'ы снова в int используется метод intValue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    NSNumber *intNumber = [numbers objectAtIndex:i]; // или можно просто numbers[i];

    int intValue = [intNumber intValue]; // или можно через точку просто intNumber.intValue;

    NSLog(@"Int value of number %@ is %d", intNumber, intValue);
}
```

Comment: Лучше все-таки литералы, т.к. компилятор сам разберется какого типа переданная переменная, даже с typedef'ом.

Comment: @AlexDenisov, я обновил ответ. Наверное, тут всё сильно зависит от контекста. В общем случае, кажется, ответ сейчас выглядит адекватно. Согласны?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, даже более чем :)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ с примером.

Answer (score 0):

это вам поможет [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), а так `int` это `NSInteger`

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@1, @2, @3]];
```

Comment: Насколько помню, NSInteger может быть и long-ом, от платформы зависит. В остальном все правильно, хотя при работе с большими массивами мне кажется лучше будет все же задействовать либо плюсовый вектор, либо сишный динамический массив

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать для этого Objective-C++.

Переименуйте ваш файл в `Fooo.mm`, это позволит компилятору понять что здесь есть C++

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

@implementation Fooo
{
    vector<NSUInteger> _scalarVector;
}
// ...
- (void)someMethod {
    _scalarVector.push_back(42);
}
```

**Note:** многие iOS девелоперы считают это плохой практикой из-за беспочвенной ненависти к C++, потому будьте аккуратны, и никогда не выносите C++ в публичный интерфейс вашего класс - это заставит разносить его по всему проекту, это может быть не очень здорово.